# Most efficient way to subset a query to a list of dates (across two columns) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am querying a table in a PG database which contains a `period` (`character varying(255)`) and a `value` (`integer`), which looks something like:

```
|period|value|
|Months|3    |
|Months|6    |
|Weeks |1    |
|Years |5    |
```

After a few joins, I'm looking to subset my result set to only include a subset of these period / value combinations, for example I may only want 3 Months, 6 Months and 5 Years (so not 1 Weeks).

I'd usually reach to a `WHERE IN(..)` but don't think I can do this across two columns. Instead I've tried to make a composite column by:

`CURRENT_DATE + CAST(CONCAT(tbl.value, tbl.period) AS INTERVAL)`

Producing a column of `timestamp`s which I can then subset with an `IN('2019-05-18', '2019-08-18', '2024-02-18')`.

This works but isn't particularly pretty or efficient. Is there a better way?

I'm free to change my query (so I can subset by dates as I currently am, or by `3` and `Months`) but importantly I do not know ahead of time whether 2 Years will be stored as 24 Months (nor do I have control of the table).

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to select? You want to select all current_timestamp + 5 MOnth rows?

Comment: You should define only a single column of type `interval` that would make your life much easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say

```
WHERE (period, value) IN (('months', 5), ...)
```

and use an index over both columns.

I hope I got the syntax right; there might be a `ROW` missing somewhere.